# Django, how to ForeignKey(auth_user)?

Tags: django

I am a newbie of django. I want to make a ForeignKey to the `auth_user` table.

I try to do that:

`user = models.ForeignKey(auth_user)`

It cause the error:

`NameError: name 'auth_user' is not defined`

So, can somebody tell me how to import `auth_user`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since foreign keys accept strings, you can use the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting in your foreign key.

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

This works whether you are using the built in `User` model, or a custom model.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are talking about django.contrib.auth.models.User then do

```
from  django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyModel(models.model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

If you are talking about a custom User model that comes from elsewhere, replace the import with the relevent import for that class.

Comment: You should always use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL as @Alasdair mentioned. It keeps your code extensible and the migrations are handled properly.